# How to disable static initializer?

Tags: jmockit

Assuming my system under test looks like this:

```
public class SysUnderTest {
    public int foo() {
        Trouble trouble1 = new Trouble();
        Trouble trouble2 = new Trouble();
        return trouble1.water(1) + trouble2.water(2);
    }
}
```

The test will looks something like

```
public class DummyTest {

    @Tested SysUnderTest sut;
    @Mocked Trouble trouble;

    @Test
    public void testTrouble() {
        new Expectations() {{
            trouble.water(anyInt); returns(10, 20);
        }};

        assertThat("mocked result", sut.foo(), is(30));

        new FullVerificationsInOrder() {{
            Trouble t1 = new Trouble();
            Trouble t2 = new Trouble();
            t1.water(1);
            t2.water(2);
        }};
    }
}
```

However, `Trouble` is actually a 3rd-party lib class that I have no control, which it does static initialization which will fail in testing env.

```
public class Trouble {
    static {
        troubleInitialize();
    };

    public int water(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    private static void troubleInitialize() {
        throw new RuntimeException("Trouble");
    }
}
```

I know I can use `MockUp<Trouble>` to get rid of the static initializer but I have no idea how to make use of it in case as I want to (in my realistic case) be able to distinguish the two new instances (created in SysUnderTest) and verify their invocations.  I have tried different ways but all failed with some reasons

1. Adding a `new MockUp<Trouble>(){@Mock void $clinit(){} };` in `@Before`/`@BeforeClass`, and keep `@Mocked Trouble trouble;`.  It seems not working because the mockup action happens after the `DummyTest` class is loaded, which will load (unmodified) `Trouble` class which will throw exception during static initialization
2. Adding the new Mockup in a `TestSuite` and call the `DummyTest` in suite, similar problem as 1.
3. Simply put the behavior of returning `20, 30` in the fake class, and remove usage of `Expectations/Verifications` but I have no way to verify which instance is called with what parameter.

Is there a better way to solve my problem? Actually I would want to keep using `Expectaitons/Verifications`, all I want is some way to disable the static initializer during unit test.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [stubOutClassInitialization](http://jmockit.org/api1x/mockit/Mocked.html#stubOutClassInitialization--) to change the mocked class's static init to an empty method when using Mocked.

```
@Mocked(stubOutClassInitialization=true) Trouble trouble;
```

Comment: Can't imagine I missed this feature! It does exactly what I am expecting!

Comment: Glad to have an easy answer.  :)